# Interpretation of PolarPlot

Tags: plotting, trigonometry, education

I tried to plot the function $r=-2t$ with $t$ in $[0,2\pi]$:

```
PolarPlot[-2 t, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

When $t=\pi/4$, I have:

$$r=-\pi/2=-1.57$$

Through Get Coordinates, I saw the only point so that $r=-1.57$ is $("-"1.57, \,\, 3.9...)$. Why is the angle $3.9..=\pi+(\pi/4)$ different from $t=\pi/4$?

How can I get the above angle by using math formulas? I can't use the classic relationship $tan(t)=y/x$ because I don't know x and y (without looking the plot).

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: That is your problem, the point you measured has r = 1.57. If you want to get an angle for r = -1.57 you need to reflect that point through the origin.

Comment: Hello @Kuba, can you explain your comment please? If the angle is unknown, how can I do the reflection? Maybe the angle is $\pi/4$?

Comment: I think the confusion here is what exactly does GetCoordinates give for PolarPlot

Comment: If you have a point (1,1) cartesian, is it (sqrt(2), Pi/4) or (-sqrt(2), 3Pi/4)? My point is that information that you use negative radius is gone so you have to think about it yourself.

Comment: @Kuba Ok, your example is clear. I have the inverse problem: given $r=-1.57$, what is the angle (without knowing x and y)?

Comment: `t = -r/2` and `r = -Pi/2` which means `t = Pi / 2 /2 = Pi /4`?

Comment: Hi @Kuba, by looking the plot I see that the right angle is $\pi+(\pi/4)$, that is almost 3.9 (check it by using Get Coordinates please). Is there a way to get the right angle through math formulas?

Comment: @Kuba please tell me what is in my case $x^2$ anf $f$.

Comment: I'm deleting previous comment as I don't have time for discussion and it was off topic anyway. Please explain clearly what do you want to achieve in  Mathematica and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we have an example of incorrect use of the polar radius function `r[t]`, which by definition must be positive or zero, $r\ge 0$. Mathematica offers a kind of solution for $r<0$ using the Euler formula $-1=e^{i\pi}$, and interpreting multiplication by $-1$ as a rotation of $\pi$. In this case,$\pi$ is added to the argument `t`. This is where the strange data comes from.

```
PolarPlot[{-2*t, 2*t} , {t, 0, Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello @AlexTrounev, thank you very much for your excellent explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!